# how to select record id in oracle apex interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how can I get the id (or some other column value) of the selected record in interactive report ? I can't use Interactive grid because it doesn't allow downloading xls or rtf export of report in action menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever created a "report with form on a table" (which is an interactive report that calls a form), then check reports' **attributes**.

Under the **Link** property, you'll see the **Target** button - click it. It'll show the way you pass interactive report's value to a form. You'll notice that it is referenced as `#ID#` (or `#EMP_NAME#` or whatever).

Comment: ... and the reference represents any column alias from the report.